# How to compare two arrays of chars and store different value between the two

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I'm at my wits' end here (which isn't saying very much). My program takes two forms of user input, a sentence and a word to be stripped from that sentence. The sentence has a fixed size of 101 characters, and the word to be stripped, has a fixed size of 5. Although strings and vectors would make this much easier, I would like to only use char arrays.

The problem that I seem to be having is comparing arrays of two different sizes. I try to loop through the sentence length and compare each individual element in the sentence and key word to be removed. The issue is that I can't get the key word to compare with every word in the sentence, but only the first (if there's a match). The code to compare these two char arrays is

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(sentence); i++)
{
    if (sentence[i] == keyword[i])
                sentence[i] = ' ';
}
```

The thought process here is to directly compare each individual element, and if there's a match, replace that instance with a space, to 'deconstruct' the sentence. That way, the user can see how their sentence looks after removing all instances of their 'key' word entered. For example, the keyword 'anti' compared to the sentence 'antivenom is antinice' would yield 'venom is nice.'
Assume that all user input is converted to lowercase and punctuation is removed to ease this comparison.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I compare the 'key' word to every single word found in the user sentence? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use `std::strstr()` to search for a substring in a string.

Comment: If you don't use built-in functions like that, you need a nested loop. At each position in the sentence, you need a loop to compare with all the characters in `keyword`. You also can't use the same index `i` in both arrays -- you need to compare `keyword[0]` with `sentence[i]`, `keyword[1]` with `sentence[i+1]`, and so on.

Comment: And you can't replace anything until you get to the end of the inner loop and succesfully match the entire keyword.